# Dynamicly load dll in fitnesse fixture

Tags: dll, load, fixtures, fitnesse

I'm trying to write a FitNesse fixture against an interface (in c#).  I want to be able to have the fixture dynamically load the implementation from a dll (so that I can use the same tests against different implementations of the same interface...i.e. mock data, live data, etc.).  I have a init method in my fixture that takes 2 strings, a class name and a dll name.  I call Assembly.LoadFrom(dllname) in the method.  I get the following error with that call:  "Invalid Directory on URL".

Any ideas?  It sounds like the dll name is getting mangled somehow in the translation...

The table looks like this:
|Init Provider From Dll|SlmLicenseDataErrorProvider|TestModelProvider.dll|

Thanks in advance...

-Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to add a !path somewhere to point to the location of your assemblies.  By default Fitnesse.Net (or FitSharp, or whatever it is these days) usually defaults its working directory to the location of the FitServer.exe executable (or SlimServer.exe or whatever it is these days).  If your assembly isn't in that directory, or in the default assembly search paths or the GAC then fitnesse may simply not be finding it?